# Automatic control of linear system with non independent inputs

Tags: control-theory

I'm currently trying to (re)learn automatic control 2 years after having finished college, and I'm having a hard time. I'm trying to control a simplistic lunar lander in a 2d space.

The only way to control it is to change its angle and/or thrust power, so I have the following state-space representation:

$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}
   x_1 \\
   x_2 \\
   x_3 \\
   x_4
   \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{gather}
 \dot{x}
 =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   x\;+
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
   u
\end{gather}
$$

Where:

- x$_1$ is the horizontal position
- x$_2$ is the vertical position
- x$_3$ is the horizontal velocity
- x$_4$ is the vertical velocity

And u is the command, accelerations on respectively the horizontal and vertical coordinates.
My problem is the acceleration is unidirectional, and its horizontal and vertical components are correlated:

$$
\begin{gather}
 u
 =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a\times\cos{\theta} \\
   a\times\sin{\theta} - g
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
$$

$a$ is the acceleration provided by the thruster and $\theta$ is the angle of the lander. $g$ is the gravity constant.

Since the system is linear, I could calculate the feedback control with the gain K, but I realize this K would consider the two input commands are independent.

I've been stuck on this for a few days, I've tried including $\theta$ and $a$ in $x$ so $u$ could simply be an angular velocity and an acceleration derivative, which would be independent, but then the system becomes nonlinear and I have no idea how to solve it.

Maybe my approach is wrong, but I'm honestly lost here, could anyone explain to me what I did wrong or how I could take this input restriction into account in the feedback loop?

ADDENDUM 1: I'm considering for the sake of simplicity that I can freely and instantly change $\theta$ and $a$.

Comment: What would be the dynamics of $\theta$, $\dot{\theta}=\tau$ with $\tau$ the torque input to the system?

Comment: Here I'm considering I can freely change $\theta$ and $a$, in order to make things simple so I guess $\dot{\theta}$ would be a Dirac delta function? I'm not sure this is the correct term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a$ and $\theta$ are essentially [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates). So if you have a state feedback control law $u=-K\,x$ then you can solve for $a$ and $\theta$ given each value for $u$. Namely

\begin{align}
a &= \sqrt{u_1^2 + (u_2 + g)^2} \\
\theta &= \text{atan2}(u_2 + g, u_1)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)